# 2 Geometric Distribution's compute covariance of max and min

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given 2 Geometric distribution independent random variables $X,Y ~ G(1/2)$.

Compute the Covariance of $W,Z$ such that $W=min(X,Y) , Z = max(X,Y)$.

I have computed that $W ~ G(3/4)$ and I try to compute the following equation -

$Cov(W,Z) = Cov(W,X+Y-W) = Cov(W,-W)+Cov(W,X)+Cov(W,Y) = -Var(W) + Cov(W,X) + Cov(W,Y) = -Var(W) + 2Cov(W,X)$

as $Cov(W, X) = Cov(W,Y)$.

$Cov(W, X) = E[WX] - E[W]E[X]$.

$E[WX] = E[WX|X>Y]P(X>Y) + E[WX|Y>X]P(Y>X) + E[WX|X=Y]P(X=Y)$

I have computed that $P(X>Y)=P(X<Y)=P(X=Y) = 1/3$

But I'm stuck computing the expected value given that a certain event occurred.

Hope to get help.

Comment: $E[WZ]=E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]=(E[X])^2$. You only need to find $E[W]$ and $E[Z]$.